# unity android gameobject not working

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

So in my app i pass a game object, called datacontroller through out my three scenes. The persistent scene is an empty scene, the menuscreen scene and then the game scene. My application works perfectly on my computer and in editor mode but when i download the apk to my android tablet it no longer works! iv'e read this may have to do with my code for my object but i dont think i written anything that only works in the editor.

```
enter code here
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;                                                             // The System.IO namespace contains functions related to loading and saving 
files

public class DataController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private RoundData[] allRoundData;
    private PlayerProgress playerProgress;

private string gameDataFileName = "data.json";

void Start()
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);

    LoadGameData();

    LoadPlayerProgress();

    SceneManager.LoadScene("MenuScreen");
}

public RoundData GetCurrentRoundData()
{
    // If we wanted to return different rounds, we could do that here
    // We could store an int representing the current round index in PlayerProgress

    return allRoundData[0];
}

public void SubmitNewPlayerScore(int newScore)
{
    // If newScore is greater than playerProgress.highestScore, update playerProgress with the new value and call SavePlayerProgress()
    if (newScore > playerProgress.highestScore)
    {
        playerProgress.highestScore = newScore;
        SavePlayerProgress();
    }
}

public int GetHighestPlayerScore()
{
    return playerProgress.highestScore;
}

private void LoadGameData()
{
    // Path.Combine combines strings into a file path
    // Application.StreamingAssets points to Assets/StreamingAssets in the Editor, and the StreamingAssets folder in a build
    string filePath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, gameDataFileName);

    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        // Read the json from the file into a string
        string dataAsJson = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        // Pass the json to JsonUtility, and tell it to create a GameData object from it
        GameData loadedData = JsonUtility.FromJson<GameData>(dataAsJson);

        // Retrieve the allRoundData property of loadedData
        allRoundData = loadedData.allRoundData;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("Cannot load game data!");
    }
}

// This function could be extended easily to handle any additional data we wanted to store in our PlayerProgress object
private void LoadPlayerProgress()
{
    // Create a new PlayerProgress object
    playerProgress = new PlayerProgress();

    // If PlayerPrefs contains a key called "highestScore", set the value of playerProgress.highestScore using the value associated with that key
    if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("highestScore"))
    {
        playerProgress.highestScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highestScore");
    }
}

// This function could be extended easily to handle any additional data we wanted to store in our PlayerProgress object
private void SavePlayerProgress()
{
    // Save the value playerProgress.highestScore to PlayerPrefs, with a key of "highestScore"
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("highestScore", playerProgress.highestScore);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I am starting to go through tutorials of unity myself so I am not an expert. :)

But what I would try is the first thing. `using System.IO;` not sure if this will work to get files on android because android has a different file structure. So I would first remove it and sort of hard code the file path or comment out the code using System.IO classes then recompile apk in unity and check if it works. I also saw this post : http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1023391/systemio-dont-work-on-android.html

If that did not work I would comment functionality out and compile apk and check if its working if its not comment more code out until you find the line or the code that causes it to error on android. This method takes long to troubleshoot or get your code causing the problem but for me this has worked before.

I am guessing as it is working on you pc its a class or something its referencing that's not available in android.

Please share your findings if you figure out what part of the code does it. As I would also want to know to prevent me from doing it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the use of System.IO on Android and in general on Unity.

Use "**Resources**" instead, just following this steps:

- Create a folder called "Resources"
- Move json file on it and rename in .txt
- Use this code to get the string:

```cs
var file = Resources.Load("filename_here") as TextAsset;
Debug.Log(file.text)
```